Hyperledger-Fabric AMB connect to Typescript
I tried to connect Hyperledger fabric(AMB) 2.2 using typescript but I am getting errors so Plz provide any tutorial or repository link for this?
I tried with typescript code in fabric - samples 2.2 repository, I stored my keys in wallet then tried but it unable to connect
Then I tried fabric client in typescript when I use client I am getting error below
gatewaytest.ts:94:31 - error TS2339: Property 'loadFromConfig' does not exist on type 'typeof Client'.
94   const client = FabricClient.loadFromConfig(
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gatewaytest.ts:102:37 - error TS2339: Property 'newCryptoSuite' does not exist on type 'typeof Client'.
102   const crypto_suite = FabricClient.newCryptoSuite();
Method 2:
So I tried in fabric-network module by using gateway, In gateway connect we get keys from aws secrets so unable to connect wallet. it doesnot support secret key values in wallet parameter below
await gateway.connect(ccp, {
wallet,
identity: username,
discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true }, // Enable discovery
});
Method 3:
Then we tried to create wallet and stores in that try to connect but It unable to connect us as well as no error logs.
Please, help me to resolve this issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If your credentials (certificate and private key) are being injected at runtime as secrets, there are two obvious options open to you when using the fabric-network API:

Create an in-memory wallet and store the credentials there in the shape of an X509Identity, using any label of your choice. Then pass the wallet and identity label in the options passed to the Gateway connect() method.
Just supply the credentials in the shape of an X509Identity as the identity property of the options passed to the Gateway connect() method.

In both cases, in a deployment where nodes (peers and orderers) have their own public IP name/address and are not just running in a Docker network on the local machine, the asLocalhost option should be false.
For option 1, the code might look something like this:
const wallet = await Wallets.newInMemoryWallet();
const id: X509Identity = {
    mspId: 'MyOrg',
    type: 'X.509',
    credentials: {
        certificate: secrets.certificatePem,
        privateKey: secrets.privateKeyPem,
    },
}
await wallet.put('MyID', id);

const gateway = new Gateway();
try {
    await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, {
        wallet,
        identity: 'MyID',
        discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: false },
    });
    //...
} finally {
    gateway.disconnect();
}

For option 2, the code might look something like this:
const id: X509Identity = {
    mspId: 'MyOrg',
    type: 'X.509',
    credentials: {
        certificate: secrets.certificatePem,
        privateKey: secrets.privateKeyPem,
    },
}

const gateway = new Gateway();
try {
    await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, {
        identity: id,
        discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: false },
    });
    //...
} finally {
    gateway.disconnect();
}

